# "Among themselves" or "among them"?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

Which sentence is correct?

> 1. ...where successful people are giving lectures and people could
>      exchange knowledge among themselves.
> 2. ...where successful people are giving lectures and people could exchange knowledge among them.

Comment: In this sentence, *them* would exclude the subject (*people*), so you probably mean *themselves*.

Comment: Yes, a reflexive object must be used only when there is a coreferential subject. In _He shot himself_ subject and object are the same, but in _He shot him_ they're not.

Comment: The sentence uses the present progressive and "could."  I think it's better to use "can."

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that neither ending is needed.  Isn't it sufficient to say:

> ...where successful people are giving lectures and people could exchange knowledge.

I don't think *among them/selves* adds anything useful. Who else would they be exchanging knowledge with? People that weren't there?!

But if you must have an ending, what about:

> ...where successful people are giving lectures and people could exchange knowledge **with each other**.

As an aside, I think I would have said ***amongst*** themselves if using those words.

Answer (score 0):

Themselves is reflexive pronoun, and them is objective pronoun. 
Now, according to rules, we should use objective pronoun after preposition; here "among" is the preposition.
eg- between you and me.

Comment: Hello, Rahul. 'We left the tidying-up to them' And 'They talked amongst themselves' show that a rule insisting that either type of pronoun is mandatory, is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, Mr. Edwin... you are right; it is not mandatory to use either pronoun, and it seems superfluous. Even so, if a writer chooses, he or she must abide by the rules of the English grammar.
reference- Grammar Girl , Longman English Grammar

Comment: Mignon Fogarty (Grammar Girl) and Longman would not claim that either 'We left the tidying-up to them' or 'They talked amongst themselves' is ungrammatical. Please show the exact place where you have found 'according to rules, we should use objective pronoun after preposition', as you put it. Have a look at the most upvoted answer in the [Usage of reflexive pronouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134572/usage-of-reflexive-pronouns) thread.

Answer (score -1):

While I agree with TrevorD that the better answer is to leave off the preposition entirely, it's worth pointing out that "amoung them" is particularly incorrect. The meaning would read as follows:

> ... where successful people are giving lectures and **[*other*] people** could exchange knowledge among them.

Answer (score -4):

People can't share anything among themselves.

Consider:

- I can't give anything to myself.
- We can't give anything to ourselves.

Comment: Sorry but this is actually wrong. "We gave ourselves a pat on the back for a job well done." (Metaphorical, probably, but definitely possible)