# Why did the writer use "him", instead of "himself"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, reflexives

> On a visit one evening to Nathaniel Hawthorne and his wife, Herman Melville, MobyDick author, told them a story of a fight he had witnessed on an island in the South Seas, in which one of the Polynesian warriors had wreaked havoc among his foes with a heavy club. Striding about the room, Melville demonstrated the feats of bravery and the desperate drama of the battle. After he had gone, Mrs. Hawthorne thought she remembered that he had left empty-handed, and wondered, “Where is that club with which Mr. Melville was laying about **him** so?” Mr. Hawthorne maintained that he must have taken it with **him**, and indeed a search of the room revealed nothing. The next time they saw him, they asked him what had happened to the club. It turned out that there was no club; it had simply been a figment of their imagination, conjured up by the vividness of Melville’s narrative.

Question: Why did the writer use "him", instead of "himself"?

Comment: Question: Why do you think he should have used himself rather than him?

Comment: @Jim Because an NP that is coreferential with an earlier NP in the same clause must usually be a reflexive.

Comment: The reason is that  if the second noun occurs in a locative phrase (i.e. one that tells us about location or direction) it doesn’t need to be reflexive. Compare “She was beside herself with rage” but “She kept her books beside her”.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Pretend there are are three English teachers from different parts of the world looking for help to explain a tricky grammar issue, and write your answer to *them*. Go on, I know you want to. You are "here" and I enjoy reading the grammar debates but then someone comes and shifts them to chat–what a waste!

Comment: This on English Language Learners is pretty much exactly the same question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/160985/correct-usage-of-him-and-himself

Comment: @Mari-LouA I did. I then pretended to write them an answer! ;-) [SE hasn't done enough yet ...]

Comment: Sorry, I got stuck on "Nathaniel Hawthorne and *his wife, Herman Melville*."

Comment: I'd have certainly used 'himself' and 'him' in that order. But does [Which prepositions are followed by accusative pronouns instead of reflexive pronouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134572/which-prepositions-are-followed-by-accusative-pronouns-instead-of-reflexive-pron) not address this? Usage is tricky; 'He was wearing the belt tightly fastened around him/self' are both idiomatic.

Answer (score -2):

Asking why the author used the word "him" instead of the word "himself" is a bit like asking why the door hinges squeak on the front door of a house which is half dilapidated.

The passage of text you provided is not very well written.

The difference between "him" and "himself" is the least of our problems.